# Increasing speed of a video in C# ?

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

I am trying to increase the speed of a video using NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegConverter

Here is what I have tried.

```
  var ffMpeg = new NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegConverter();
  string inputfile = @"C:\Users\Alan\Desktop\Video.flv";
  string outputfile = @"C:\Users\Alan\Desktop\converted.mp4";


  ConvertSettings convertSettings = new ConvertSettings
        {
            MaxDuration = 10,
            VideoFrameRate = 12
            //VideoFrameCount = 10

        };

ffMpeg.ConvertMedia(inputfile,Format.flv, outputfile,Format.mp4,convertSettings);
```

What I want is like a video with an increased playback like in this example - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6tQ1ewhGiwk

This is what I am basically trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by creating a custom convert settings with CustomOutputArgs.

```
ConvertSettings convertSettings = new ConvertSettings {

      CustomOutputArgs = "-filter_complex \"[0:v]setpts = 0.5 * PTS[v];[0:a] atempo=2.0[a]\" -map \"[v]\" -map \"[a]\""

 };

ConvertLiveMediaTask s = ffMpeg.ConvertLiveMedia(videostream, Format.mp4, outputfile, Format.mp4, convertSettings);

s.Start();
s.Wait();
```